# Create a tidb database on docker compose

Tags: docker, tidb

I have a docker-compose.yml file with the tidb container setup like this

```
  ti-db:
    image: pingcap/tidb
    container_name: ti-db
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    logging:
      driver: none
    volumes:
      - ./storage/tidb:/var/lib/mysql
```

I am trying to have it create a database called "messageservice" on startup but cannot get it to work.

In the same docker-compose file I have a mysql container where I create initial databases using init.sql file and mapping it to docker-entrypoint-initdb.d like this

```
 - ./dbInit/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

But when I do the same thing for TiDb it does not work.

Is there a way I can setup the docker-compose file so the database gets created on docker compose up command ?

Answer (score 0):

And what do you have on file init.sql?

```
services:
  ti-db:
    image: pingcap/tidb
    container_name: ti-db
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    logging:
      driver: none
    volumes:
      - ./storage/tidb:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

Or you can try without the file by using "command"

```
services:
  ti-db:
    image: pingcap/tidb
    container_name: ti-db
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    logging:
      driver: none
    volumes:
      - ./storage/tidb:/var/lib/mysql
    command: --store=tikv --path="127.0.0.1:2379" --log-file="/var/log/tidb.log" --log-level=debug && mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P4000 -uroot -e "create database messageservice;"
```

Comment: init.sql only has one line CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS messageservice;

Answer (score 0):

[tidb-docker-compose](https://github.com/pingcap/tidb-docker-compose) doesn't support `./dbInit/...`, You need to execute the initialization SQL file manually.

BTW, I recommend you to ask questions here: https://ask.pingcap.com/, this is the official forum.